# How can I always launch a program as administrator without right-clicking?

Tags: windows-7, boot, administrator

I have a program I have to run as admin. Now I have to manually do a right click and choose from the menu "Run as admin"

I'm wondering if I could create an icon with some parameter and than just double click on this icon and this program run under admin rights.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a shortcut to you program (in Explorer drag the exe somewhere with the right mouse button to get menu with create shortcut option).

Right click on the short cut, select properties and the compatibility tab has an option to always run as administrator.

Comment: You can also do this without a shortcut by simply right-clicking the executable, choosing properties switch to "compatability" tab and then check "run as an administrator". This will run it as admin without regard to how it is launched.

Answer (score 1):

Create a shortcut for that. Right click on that shortcut, Properties, Advanced, Run As Admin, Ok, Ok.